# What is the difference between Outlets and Referencing Outlets in the IB Inspector window under the connection tap?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I know that IBOutlet is a compiler directive indicating that the following variable declaration is acting as a connection point to other objects.  The 2 terms in the Inspector window can be confusing to beginners.  They look like 2 kinds of Outlets. But they may mean being an Outlet and Outlets from other objects that are being referenced.  Can somebody who is more knowledgable confirm this ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Outlets are outlets on the object itself. You connect them to other objects. Referencing Outlets are outlets on other objects that are connected to the object you're looking at. The New Referencing Outlet line lets you draw a connection in reverse.

Comment: When you say "New Referencing line" are you saying that this is a new feature in IB ?  And that we can work without it if we always draw connection in the forward direction?

Comment: New feature? I don't think so. I think it's been there as long as I can remember. Normally you draw connections by ctrl/right-clicking and dragging from the source to the destination. By doing a right-click on the destination, you can click and drag from the circle next to "New Referencing Outlet" to drag a connection in the reverse direction.